# Simulate a banner rotator with an animated GIF

Tags: animated-gif

I've been using a faulty DotNetNuke banner rotator and I just want to have one image transform into another over and over. Can I do this with an a animated GIF, and is there a tool to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) for this:

> gm convert -delay 200 -loop 50 frame*.gif animation.gif

Which would give you a delay of 2 seconds between each frame and a looping image.

If you so desired you could also use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) with essentially the same syntax.

If you're on Windows there are also some other options that are less powerful but more user friendly:

- [UnFREEz](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/unfreez/)
- [Animated GIF banner-maker](http://www.banner-maker.net/)